# Customize Storefront Theme for single site

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to customize my wordpress theme for a single site only.

I copied the `page.php` file and tried to get rid of the header by removing the `get_header();` call.
Somehow this messes with the total layout and the plugin I'am trying to use is not working properly anymore.

Is there a way to disable certain parts in an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you remove header call it will remove the header from single page. 
Would you like to use another menu built with plugin ?

If yes , you can register an new menu in functions.php and than call it in your new page.php

Hope this helped you.